# compressed property in ADX external table creation

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Lets say we create an external ADX table with compressed set to true:-

```
with(compressed=true)
```

After this if we export data to this external table, assuming the external table kind is `adl` (I don't think this matters) , since the compression is achieved in memory in the ADX cluster before data is exported , this will cause in lesser amount of data getting exported I believe , saving bandwidth. Is that a right assumption? Though, I think if the external table dataformat is either orc or parquet, this might not matter as these formats are already compressed considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exporting compressed data will write less data to the storage account and consume less bandwidth. You can use gzip or snappy compression with parquet format as well.